# CSS background image on screen resize

Tags: css, html

I have this strange issue working with css when i resize the screen (or even if I run my site . I'll post the screenshots before explaining the problem, so you can get the idea properly.
[image: BEFORE (1366x768)]

[image: AFTER (1920X1080]

My problem basically consists in this strange behaviour of CSS where my background image goes "down" when the screen resolution gets higher. I've already tried **top: 0;**, but it doesn't seem to be the solution. I think the problem may be with my background-image property, but since I'm a CSS newbie, I don't know how to fix it. What I want is that on every screen, the "inner" image must stay right below the "outer" image, like in the first photo. I post my code, hope somebody can help me!

```
    .container-titolo-index-big-background {
    background: url("../img/home/1.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.container-titolo-index { 
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    background: url("../img/home/2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    animation: slideshowHome 16s infinite;
    height: 430px;
}
```

I don't think it could help, but I post you also the animation code

```
@keyframes slideshowHome {
0% {background: url("../img/home/2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}
16% {background: url("../img/home/3.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}
32% {background: url("../img/home/4.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}
48% {background: url("../img/home/5.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}
64% {background: url("../img/home/6.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}
80% {background: url("../img/home/1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}
100% {background: url("../img/home/2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}
```

}

and also my index code

```
<div class="container-titolo-index-big-background">
    <div class="container-titolo-index"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to make you background to take 100% width or make them same width

Comment: Why's your inner div taller than your outer div?  Also where does that padding come from?  As far as I can tell, your inner div should completely cover the outer div.  Please create a [MCVE]

Comment: @Pete because it's an optical "illusion" let's say, that's because I wanted the inner image to be like outside the outer div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed what the problem was. Since i wrote

`background: url("../img/home/2.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;`

the image was always in the center of the screen. To avoid the strange behaviour on resize and stick the image to the top, you have to use

`background: url("../img/home/2.jpg") no-repeat center top fixed;`